# iMacro Cannot download image generated by PHP

Tags: imacros

I would like to download the barcode image generated by the Barcode Generator(http://www.barcode-generator.org/)

Barcode type:
Code 128

Test Barcode:
2012546435231

Size:
Smaller

I have recorded a imacro to do this. However, the function SAVEPICTUREAS does not work.

How to solve the problem?

```
VERSION BUILD=8871104 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://www.barcode-generator.org/
TAG POS=5 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:barcode
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:data CONTENT=2012546435231
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:size CONTENT=%1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:fbut
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://www.barcode-generator.org/getfile.php?file=edc51a721012c83824e0c09d90d11189/2012546435231.png CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEPICTUREAS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a variant, replace your last line of code with:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ALT:resulting<SP>barcode CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT
```

Comment: How to retain the original name of the image? Thanks

Comment: Also as a variant:  `... SET brcId 2012546435231 ... TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:data CONTENT={{brcId}} ... ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE={{brcId}} WAIT=YES ...`